# Flash animations with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, css

How does something like this work without Flash?

http://www.dirtyphonebook.com/dashboard/425-205-1921

I right-clicked on it but there's no Flash menu. I love Flash because its stable and works. But is using some sort of Javascript hack for this kind of complex behavior actually a good idea?

Comment: It isn't a Javascript "hack".

Comment: hack is probably a poor choice of words. But its not things companies normally do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you sent seems to have been created using [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) (Scalable Vector Graphics). [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html) is some documentation on how to start animating. There's a library named [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) that can help you achieve those results.

You could also use a framework like jQuery to animate elements on a page. There's a tutorial on how to animate a cartoon using jQuery found [here](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-robot/)

Answer (score 3):

The source code says they used [this JS library](http://raphaeljs.com/), Raphael, to do it.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few Javascript frameworks that allow for animation (jQuery etc).

It's not a hack - it's creative use of DHTML.

The downside is that Javascript can eat the browser's memory.  Flash, on the other hand, runs parallel to the browser (as a separate application) and so can be faster when rendering animated effects.  BUT Flash requires the Flash Player plugin, which must be installed separately and may not be available for all browsers and in all devices.

So, both Flash and animation via Javascript have pros and cons.

HTML5, which Apple states will replace Flash, is not yet supported across the board, and will apparently offer even easier animation options.

Hope this helps.  Unfortunately this is a "what is your opinion" sort of thing, rather than a cut and dried answer.

Comment: "The downside is that Javascript can eat the browser's memory." Given that Flash eats large amounts of both memory and CPU, I don't think this is really a downside of JS.

Comment: It's not a downside of anything. Both DHTML and Flash use lots of CPU and memory if you use them to do things that use a lot of CPU and memory. They both don't when you don't.

Comment: It might be an acceptable tradeoff in certain circumstances though.